# how to use context on PendingIntent in android service class?

Tags: android

My app is trying to get the USB device list. My class `extends` `Service` but when I try use `AsyncTask` a `NullPointerException` occurs.

```
@Override 
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
     Context context = MainActivity.getMainActivity();

     UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

     HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
     Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
     while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();

        String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "my packagename.USB_PERMISSION";
        PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0); //NULLPOINTEXCEPTION;
        manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        .
        .
       }
  }
```

**Logcat**

```
Process: blackeyeonandroid.iosystem.co.kr.toastama, PID: 15069
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:526)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:515)
       at blackeyeonandroid.iosystem.co.kr.toastama.MyService$DeviceDetectAsync.doInBackground(MyService.java:124)
       at blackeyeonandroid.iosystem.co.kr.toastama.MyService$DeviceDetectAsync.doInBackground(MyService.java:105)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I think the context could be the problem, but I don't know how to get a context on service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Service is a Context itself. You don't need Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `getApplicationContext()` inside your service to get the application context.

And in your case you are try to hold Main Activity Context that is UI part and does not work in Background Services.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getApplicationContext();` instead of your MainActivity for context.

Do not make getters for your Activities since once they are destroyed they can't be reached. It will always result in a nullpointer. For context you can take it from your Application which lives through the entire life of your app.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends `Service` means use service context don't use `Activity` context and when initialize `AsyncTask` from serivce pass context

start task by passing context

```
new DoSomething(this).execute();
```

in `AsyncTask` class do like this

```
class DoSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
        private Context mContext;

        public DoSomething(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            /*Use Context here*/

            return null;
        }
    }
```